# onkeydown calling function working in IE but not in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I am calling one JavaScript function during onKeyDown event for a textbox like

```
@onkeydown="javascript:return avoidSpecialCharacters(event)"
```

The JavaScript function is getting called in IE but not in chrome, safari and mozilla. What do I need to do to get it to work in these browsers?

Comment: Can you share `avoidSpecialCharacters(event)`

Comment: seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ld7ZP/

Comment: function avoidSpecialCharacters(event)
    {
    var iChars = "!@#$%^_&=\\\';/{}[]|\":*~`+<>?";
    if(iChars.indexOf(event.char)!=-1)
    {
    return false;
    }
    }